# How can I sent get parameters with a Kohana 3 Request::factory command?

Tags: url, kohana-3, requestfactory

I have a Kohana 3 MVC application.

In a view, I can explicitly call a controller's action with this line:

```
Request::factory('/test/deliveryaddress')->execute();
```

But I want to also send a parameter to the action as well to be processed like this:

```
public function action_deliveryaddress($region_name = NULL)
{
    $view = new View('test/deliveryaddress');
    $region_name = isset($_GET['region_name']) ? $_GET['region_name'] : '';
    $view->set('region_name', $region_name);
    $this->request->response = $view;
}
```

I've tried these two attempts but they don't work:

```
Request::factory('/test/deliveryaddress?region_name=top')->execute(); //error
Request::factory('/test/deliveryaddress', array('region_name'=>'top'))->execute(); //ignored
```

**How can I send a GET variable with Request::factory() or is there a better way to send GET parameters to an action?**

Answer (score 3):

For 3.1, you can use the `query()` method of the `Request` class:

```
equest::factory('/test/deliveryaddress?)->query('region_name', 'top')->execute();
```

For 3.0, there is no real isolation, and you have to manipulate the `$_GET` array.

Answer (score 0):

use query() from Request class and in your controller

instead of:

```
$region_name = isset($_GET['region_name']) ? $_GET['region_name'] : '';
```

try:

```
$get = $this->request->query();
$region_name = isset($get['region_name']) ? $get['region_name'] : '';
```